# Artemis: Client ID set on Kuberentes pods running as replica set

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-artemis

I have an ActiveMQ Artemis queue consumer and the client id is set as hostname. This runs on kubernetes as replicaset. Now the problem is whenever a pod crashes it gets assigned new hostname and the consumer loses its state on the broker. Is there a way I can keep a consistent client id throughout the pod life-cycle? Is there a way I can all the client ids from the broker so that I can assign from a known id from an id pool?

Comment: Why can't you set the client ID from configuration value that is unique to each replicaset?

Comment: i'm using helm to install replicas. How can i identify unique value unique to some pod ? I can set properties like cilent-a and client-b but then i need to know which pod took the client-a so that other pod can take client-b

Comment: I said "unique to each replicaset" not unique to each pod. Can you elaborate on why you're setting client ID in the first place?

Comment: My app is a spring batch app. It has jms consumer which should should be durable. If it get crashed or restarted it need to consume from where it stopped previously. For this i'm using client id. Without client id it does not read old messages written before  the consumer starts

Comment: So you're using a durable topic subscription? In your question you say you have "an ActiveMQ Artemis **queue** consumer [emphasis mine]". Please clarify.

Comment: Also, what is the specific point of having replicas for your application?

Comment: Multiple pods are there to increase the message consumption from the queue. I have only one topic. Producer write to it. Two consumers which have different client ids consume from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219278/discussion-between-viraj-and-justin-bertram).

Comment: So, are you using a topic or a queue? You keep saying different things.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you and really appreciate your help.  It's a queue. Queue having multiple consumers.

Comment: If it's a queue why do you need to set the client ID? Your app can just recreate the consumer on the queue and read all the messages which accumulated while it was disconnected assuming another consumer didn't get them already. The client ID is really only useful if you're creating a **durable** subscription on a **topic**.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But with test i have noticed my consumer does not receive messages which are delivered to queue when the consumer is offline. When the consumer comes online it will receive message which are sent queue on that time not the previous message. I'm using `JmsTemplate` with `ActiveMQQueue` as destination object.

Comment: That's certainly not the expected behavior. I recommend you clarify your overall use-case, post code and configuration, and detail the behavior you're seeing. As it stands your question is confusing and vague.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: The fix was done as you suggested without client id. There were issue in queue name on producer and consumer with reference to different environments we used. Simply write to one queue and read from another. Queue consumer running as replica set consume messages without issue. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're consuming from a queue there's no need to set the client ID. Your app can just recreate the consumer on the queue and read all the messages which accumulated while it was disconnected (assuming another consumer didn't get them already). The client ID is really only useful if you're creating a durable subscription on a topic. As noted in section 6.1.2 of the JMS 2 specification:

> The only use of a client identifier defined by JMS is its mandatory use in
> identifying an unshared durable subscription or its optional use in
> identifying a shared durable or non-durable subscription.